# ios change text of default shared menu items - Copy/Paste/Delete

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextview, uimenucontroller, nslocalizedstring

I need to change the text of copy/paste/edit and delete shared menu items to Dutch language. Is there any provision in `sharedMenuController` class to give localised texts to these menu items.

I tried some solutions posted in other questions to change applications language, but this is not working and it is not a feasible solution for me.

Any help will be appritiated. Thanks

Comment: Any answer or suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

I actually have troubles with that too.
See

[Set default language at first run IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448407/set-default-language-at-first-run-ios)
TLdnR:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:@[@"nl"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ITAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

This should change the whole app language settings.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working. And setting nl to `AppleLanguages` is removing other languages from `NSDefaults`. Which is not good solution for me.

Comment: I was able to change the language of this element in the simulator on my iOS7 simulator :/

Comment: So you need the whole app to be in some language, but just the copy/paste box to be in Dutch ?

Comment: I am trying it on IOS 6 simulator.

Comment: I did it on ios 7 iPad, but still unable to change text labels. any ideas?

Comment: Thanks @Antzi: This is still not working. I tried running app first time by deleting app and running again but unable to set language to dutch. I am trying it on `ios 7`  also