# Set default language at first run IOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults, nslocale

I'm trying to set the language for my app at first run.

After seeing this question, I decided to do the same.

[Setting default language for iPhone app on first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943659/setting-default-language-for-iphone-app-on-first-run)

I adapted a bit the code, and made this:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:@[[ITConf getStringForKey:ITConfLocale]] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ITAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

But this code does not works (changes are made after second startup).
However, the following code execute without any problem:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:@[@"fr"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([ITAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I don't understand why.
ITConf returns a string from a .plist file see:

```
NSString *fileP = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Conf" ofType:@"plist"];
dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileP];
return dictionary[key];
```

I verified using LLDB, and a NSString is correctly returned, with the proper value.

It looks like black magic to me!

Answer (score 0):

Next setting in Info.plist fixed the issue with localization and storyboard RTL in my case.

[image: Set default language]

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't rely on `[NSBundle mainBundle]` to look up your configuration as referencing `[NSBundle mainBundle]` will actually configure the bundle from the (at that time unchanged) `AppleLanguages` setting.